# Find a specific date in Excel (using VBA) and paste into the cell next to it

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling to find a way to find a specific cell in VBA and select the cell to the right of it.

Here is the code, with the two relevant commands in text form. I have tried different search methods, but none are able find the date in the list. Picture one is of the "Overview" sheet, picture two is the "Data" sheet.

```
Sub Save_Button()
    Range("D6:F6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Dim varDate As Variant
    varDate = Range("C6").Value

    Sheets("Data").Select
        
    'Find the same date as the one saved in varDate in the sheet "Data"
    'Select the cell next to it

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Overview").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("D6").Select
End Sub
```

[image: Overview]
[image: Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the code you want

```
Dim foundCell As Range    
Set foundCell = Cells.Find(varDate, , , xlWhole)    
If foundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox varDate & " not found"
Else
        foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
End If
```

Just put it in where you have the comment in your code.  This code assumes that all your dates are actually dates on the worksheets, not text.

Answer (score 1):

Finding dates in worksheets can be difficult. underlying the date is a formatted number. In your code you are essentially trying to find a variant string as a number and that's not going to work.

You need to format the string as a date type (CDate) so that you can find this within the worksheet

Code you should be able to adapt is below:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blah")
    
    With ws
        .Range("D6:F6").Copy
        
        Dim sDate As String: sDate = .Range("G11").Value
        Dim srcDate As Date: srcDate = CDate(Right(sDate, Len(sDate) - InStr(sDate, ",") - 1))
        
        Dim srcRange As Range: Set srcRange = .Cells.Find(srcDate)
        If Not srcRange Is Nothing Then
            srcRange.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Generally, you should avoid select where possible and assign the specific worksheets you want to work with in the code (it will save you headaches in the future)